# Bitlocker automatic unlock, is it unsafe?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, security, bitlocker

I don't get how "automatically unlock" Bitlocker feature works on Windows 10. I have a main SSD with OS installed in it that's encrypted with bitlocker and another drive encrypted with bitlocker that automatically unlocks itself at boot.

I read in the documentation that a drive set to unlock automatically "can be unlocked only when the main OS drive is locked with bitlocker too". This looks like that it can be unlocked with whatever other main OS drive encrypted with bitlocker and not only with my own main OS drive. Does this then mean that i can put my data drive on another PC using bitlocker (on the main OS drive) and it will again automatically unlock there too?

This wouldn't make any sense at all to me but it looks like so. There is no indication saying that the couple "OS drive" and "automatically unlocked drive" is unique and it's somehow tied in some way. Is it unsafe then to unlock the drive automatically? Is there any safer way to lock it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this then mean that i can put my data drive on another PC using bitlocker (on the main OS drive) and it will again automatically unlock there too?

No, because that other PC doesn't have the unlock key stored for your data disk.

> There is no indication saying that the couple "OS drive" and "automatically unlocked drive" is unique and it's somehow tied in some way.

The way they're tied together is that the OS drive literally stores a file that contains the decryption key for the data drive. (It's stored as a `.bek` file, the same kind as a "recovery key" for the OS drive.)

BitLocker on the OS drive plays no part in unlocking the data drive. Its only purpose is to protect the auto-unlock key files – if the OS drive was itself not encrypted, there would be no real security in encrypting the data drive but then storing its unlock key right next to it.